# Python regex re.findall

Tags: python, regex

I am using Python2.7 and I encounter the following problem, I have the string:

```
s = 'No of tests:  23'
```

I am using the following the regex:

```
re.findall('No of tests: \d+',s)
```

And apparently the regex return an empty list. Any idea why?

Comment: There is a typo, `/d+` must be written as `\d+` (i.e. `r'No of tests: \d+'`). After you fixed the typo, [the issue no longer persists](https://ideone.com/Tv6M5y).

Comment: It was a typo, the issue persists.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I get `['No of tests: 23']`, as expected, on Python 2.6.6 and 3.6.0. BTW, it's a good idea to use raw strings on any regex containing backslashes.

Comment: You have 2 spaces in the text and 1 space in the pattern. Use `r'No\s+of\s+tests:\s*\d+'`

Comment: Yes with raw it works. Thank you for the help

Comment: I think it is not the raw string literal that helped, but `\s*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string contains 2 spaces before the number.

It is a good idea to use `\s*` to match any zero or more whitespace characters when the input string is user-defined and spaces may come in different number. To make sure there is 1 or more spaces, use `\s+`.

Thus, it is advisable to use

```
r'No\s+of\s+tests:\s*\d+'
```

Note that raw string literals are best when defining regex patterns in Python (you won't get any problems due to escaping special characters, not the case here though).